# AlienTiles optimistic heuristic function

Tags: heuristics

Hello I am trying to use the alienTile problem described at [www.alientiles.com](http://Alientiles.com) using the A* algorithm but I cannot find any good heuristic function so far.

In alien tiles you have a board with NxN tiles, all colored red. By clicking on a tile, all tiles in the same row and column advance by a color, the color order being red->green->blue->purple, resetting to red after purple. The goal is to change all tiles to the specified colors. The simplest goal state is all the tiles going from red to green, blue or purple. The board doesn't have to be 7x7 as the site suggests.

Is there any good point to start because I am completely frustrated about how I am supposed to handle the problem

Comment: What heuristics have you tried? Isn't "number of fields with the correct colors" or "sum of color-based distances of each field to the goal state" good enough?

Comment: @KilianFoth I have tried both of them and none is admissible, since the overestimate the cost to the solution. Also,they both doesn't 'help' the algorithm since you need to formulate a strategy on how the tiles are changed rather than going to a state with many tiles same as the target

Comment: Change the question title to mention that you need an *optimistic* heuristic, maybe then someone will think of one.

Comment: @KilianFoth thx for your time